# What happened to Ubuntu Desktop's global menu and Linux Kernel 3.8.5?

Tags: 13.04

I'm just wondering what happened to Ubuntu Desktop's global menu and Linux Kernel 3.8.5?  3.8.5 is supposed to land in raring, but my ISO (just a day old before release) doesn't have it (3.8.0-19 generic). Same thing goes with some of the applications with the global menu.  Ubuntu Desktop doesn't have it, Files, Appearance, and other application's menu has problems (repeats the name twice). Do they plan on not fixing/releasing it?

Sorry for the weird question, but the "defective" panel menu is driving me nuts. The "cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86" is also pretty frustrating (I don't want to keep unplugging my webcam every single boot).

Comment: Can't answer for the kernel issue, but Nautilus has been "upgraded" to 3.6, which basically means it looks prettier but lost a ton of functionality. The menu is now a single entry, and doesn't show up when just viewing the desktop.

Comment: Darn :( Is there any way to get the global menu back to Ubuntu Desktop by using a different file manager?  I depend on that functionality for almost everything. I'm pretty disappointed they shipped nautilus 3.6 by default.

Comment: Not sure myself. But yes, the gutting of functionality is disappointing. Complain to the GNOME devs I guess!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is based on linux v3.8.5. And wait for the final release, I guess you are using one of the latest daily builds. The appearance has changed, also its more snappier than 12.10.